# MySQL - Retrieving a row from 2 tables based on MAX(aggregatedvalue) of one table

Tags: mysql, aggregate, max

I have 2 tables with the same structure in which 3 rows of data are captured every 5 minutes. From this, I'm trying to retrieve a single row per day using the maximum aggregated value of T1. For example,

T1
dateTime | name | value
**2011-06-05 00:00:00 | Johnny  | 20

2011-06-05 00:00:00 | Robert | 30

2011-06-05 00:00:00 | Lauren | 24**
2011-06-05 00:00:05 | Johnny  | 12
2011-06-05 00:00:05 | Robert | 10
2011-06-05 00:00:05 | Lauren | 10
...
2011-06-06 00:00:00 | etc

T2
dateTime | name | value
2011-06-05 00:00:00 | Johnny  | 8
2011-06-05 00:00:00 | Robert | 12
2011-06-05 00:00:00 | Lauren | 24
2011-06-05 00:00:05 | Johnny  | 52
2011-06-05 00:00:05 | Robert | 16
2011-06-05 00:00:05 | Lauren | 25
...
2011-06-06 00:00:00 | etc

In the above example, T1's first 3 rows when aggregated have a higher value (20+30+24) than the second set of 3 rows (12+10+10). Once I have established which timestamp has the highest (MAX) aggregated value from T1, I want to grab the **relative** aggregated value from T2. In this case it would be the values at 00:00:00 which is 8+12+24. Note that this would span several days so the desired output would be:

dateTime | T1AggregatedValues | T2AggregatedValues
2011-06-05 00:00:00 | 74 | 44
2011-06-06 xTime | y | z
2011-06-07 xTime | y | z

I've tried using `SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE value=(SELECT MAX(value) FROM T1)` as a starting point but this just gives me a single max value for T1. I'm really at a loss as to how to progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT dateTime, SUM(value) AS valueSum
FROM T1
GROUP BY dateTime
ORDER BY valueSum DESC
```

This will give you all the dateTime group(s), listing the highest aggregate(s) first. Depending on your logic you'll probably have to handle the possibility of more than one dateTime group having the same aggregate value instead of assuming that the 1st result is the highest.

If you knew absolutely for sure that you'd only get 1 highest aggregate group (no possibility of a tie for highest aggregate) then you could do this:

```
SELECT dateTime, MAX(valueSum) FROM
(
    SELECT dateTime, SUM(value) AS valueSum
    FROM T1
    GROUP BY dateTime
    ORDER BY valueSum DESC
) AS sumTable
```

Whatever method you use to isolate the one group that you declare as having the highest aggregate, once you identify that group you then take the dateTime of said group and retrieve `SUM(value)` from `T2` for it.

Comment: In the 2nd query, the ORDER BY isn't necessary but I left it in to show how the 2nd query relates to the 1st one, i.e. the 1st query acts as a subquery in the 2nd.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I'm 99.9% sure that there won't be a tie when it comes to calculating aggregates. Thanks again.